# how to delete a sql table using Statements in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i have a [jtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTvCD.png)
each time a new row is created a new sql table is also created and it's named after the id of the created row. for example if i create a row with id=5 a new sql table called v5g will be created in the database.

in the same way, when i select a row and click on the delete button, the row is supposed to be deleted along with the table that was created in parallel with the row.
and this is where i'm having an issue , the row does get deleted but the sql table remains in the database. here's the code responsible for the deletion event of the sql table:

```
try {
                // TODO add your handling code here:
                DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) liste.getModel();
                Statement stmtcg = con.createStatement();
                stmtcg.execute("drop table v"+liste.getValueAt(liste.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()+"g");
                stmtcg.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior and what are you getting?

Comment: the expected behaviour: the deletion of the sql table with the name v"+liste.getValueAt(liste.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()+"g , with liste.getValueAt(liste.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString() being the value of first column of the selected row. what i'm getting right now: the sql table is not deleted and i get this error message: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1**.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and put the full exception stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try with update:

```
 String sql = "DROP TABLE v";

  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: it still doesn't delete the table, i get this error message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1"

Comment: maybe you don´t have the table. replace "v" with the existing table you want to delete